# How can I view my Instagram backup data in a friendly way?

Tags: backup, data-recovery, json, viewer, social-networking

recently i have downloaded a backup of my Instagram account ...

and the zip file contained a lot of ".json" files and i have no idea how to view

it like... the way that Instagram did

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a Look At This , I Created For the same purpose

https://github.com/mainigautam/instagram_backup_manager

Comment: it's more than perfect mate thanks a lot ... but the installation took so long and when moving or coping the folder it takes forever because of the so many files and modules especially the client one .... it Literally took me more than full six minutes to compress the folder... great but needs to be sized down or something.

Comment: Yes Working on it for sure , It was pushed like in sort of developmental phase . working on beta , will be available soon . sorry for inconvinience

Answer (score 2):

#### I have no idea how to view it like... the way that Instagram did

Probably the best you can do is convert the JSON files into CSV files and use a spreadsheet to view them. See below for more information.

> When you unzip Instagram’s data archive, you’ll see a folder that’s
>   full of a bunch of ugly JSON files. You can open these up in a text
>   editor to try and parse the raw information yourself, or you can copy
>   and paste the contents of any JSON file into a site [like this
>   one,](https://konklone.io/json/) which converts the data into a CSV that’s slightly easier to
>   read. (That’s all done within your browser, not server-side, so you
>   aren’t shipping your data off to some unknown entity.)
>
> The JSON files cover a lot of data:
>
> - Comments you’ve made to friends’ pictures (or replies to comments they’ve made on yours)
> - When you started following other Instagram users and when other Instagram users started following you
> - Who you blocked on Instagram (and when)
> - When you liked content from different users (not a list of the specific content you liked)
> - When you posted content to Instagram (and what your witty caption was)
> - All of the messages you’ve sent to other users using Instagram’s mobile apps
> - Your profile information
> - Searches you’ve made
>
> Within the archive’s folders, you can also view much of the content
>   you’ve uploaded to Instagram’s service, including:
>
> - What images you’ve sent others via direct messages
> - All of the Instagram photos you’ve uploaded
> - Instagram stories you’ve archived
> - Videos you’ve published to Instagram

Source [What's in Your Instagram Data Dump and How to Get It](https://lifehacker.com/whats-in-your-instagram-data-dump-and-how-to-get-it-1825777655)

Comment: ♦
thanks

this views it in a good way ....
but i am waiting for a better answer ... if there isn't ....... yours is considered the best one till now